# Proteus voltmeter value in simulation not right

Tags: circuit-analysis, proteus, voltmeter

I'm really new to Proteus, so if I'm doing something very wrong, sorry.

I'm messing around with the Proteus simulation but I don't understand why my voltmeter has given me a value when the circuit is open. I expected it to give a 0 V result. I tried adding a ground to the negative connection of the Voltage source but it didn't help.

Here is my circuit, with the simulation running:

[image: Circuit with a voltmeter connected to a switch and a voltmeter]

Comment: I am not sure what kind of model Proteus uses when emulating a switch, but in real life 1000V is quite a lot of voltage to put over a switch, so any impurities, moisture and ionized air between switch pins will cause conduction. Also the multimeter is not ideal, most multimeters have input impedance of roughly 20 Mohms when measuring voltages.

Comment: I though that in Proteus it would simulate a ideal circuit. I'm going to do a relay system that has to operate with 1000V so I wanted to simulate somewhere, but with this happening is quite difficult to be sure everything will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's what we call "floating": as long as that wire is connected to nothing, you can't know what happens.

It's quite realistic: if you turn on a multimeter and don't connect the Plus-Pin anywhere, it will show values.

[image: Multimeter showing a voltage with Plus-Pin not connected]

To get around this, you can ensure that this wire is never connected to nothing by adding a resistor in parallel to the meter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPY2LA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Well, not sure if this is working for me. When I use a resistor value of 10k it almost go to zero (0V) but when I use one with a higher value like yours it doesn't work.

https://i.imgur.com/61vSxXa.png